# Is it possible to add border and background to post grids? [Wordpress]

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I would like to add some border and background to my post grids to which they will be fit to my website look. Is that possible? The default one is;

[Default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFLe4.png)

And
[I want to make like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5yh4.png)

Thanks!

My website is; BattlegroundsTurkiye.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test this :)

```
.post{border : 1px red solid}
```

Comment: It didn't worked but thanks for your help. I'm still looking to how to do it. :)

Comment: Oh okay, i changed ".post" to ."homepage_pane" and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You could inspect the element and add custom CSS.

[image: Custom CSS Location]

[image: Something like this]